# Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined getting error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have json file . I am trying to get json data from json file .then I need to convert the json (change key and value) key and value because this puglin require in that formate in key and value and   https://github.com/nimbly/angular-formly .
But my problem is that istead for getting form from this plugin.
**Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined**
can you please tell where I am wrong ?
Issue reproduce .click on button (get json from a file).then you will see in console that error .I want to show form when I click to button (click to grt json A)
Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/bbd6D828TU8TpZYre9D0?p=preview

```
$scope.getFromAFile= function () {
  // body...
  var inputs=[];
  $http.get('a.json').success (function(data){
    var a=changeData(data);
          console.log('pp');

  console.log(data.studentName);
  $scope.formFields.push(a['input']);


}).error(function(err){
        alert(err);
    });

}

function changeData(data) {

    var map = { NUMBER: "number", TEXT: "text", SWITCH: "select" };

    // data is an object - use for .. in to enumerate
    for (var key in data.input) {
        var e = data.input[key];   // alias for efficient structure dereferencing
        e.label = e.displayName;
        e.title = e.displayDetail;
        e.type = map[e.inputType];

        delete e.displayName;
        delete e.displayDetail;
        delete e.inputType;
    }

    console.log('after data...');
    console.log(data);
    return data;
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `push` into an array at `$scope.formFields` which doesn't exist.

This works. http://plnkr.co/edit/p5niu38aWpN5BbIxcyZ0?p=preview

```
$scope.getFromAFile= function () {
  // body...
  var inputs=[];
  $http.get('a.json').success (function(data){
    var a=changeData(data);
          console.log('pp');

  console.log(data.studentName);
  console.log($scope);
  $scope.formFields = a['input'];


}).error(function(err){
        alert(err);
    });

}
```

Comment: thanks for answer ..!! please check there is problem ..I given four field it display only three.and secondly there is no drop down in that

Comment: There is one more issue If you click on first button .it show form and when you click on second it will not show form

Comment: do you have any idea of these issue

Comment: I haven't changed the function `getFromBFile` this is up to you.  I don't know what exactly the plugin you are using expects so that would be a different issue.

Comment: if you have any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247803/how-to-integrate-jquery-plugin-with-angular-js pleae check